# MongoDB: Get all $matched elements individually from an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get all matched elements individually, [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y2HgHdvZxsA) is the sample data and the query.

```
// json
[
  {
    "name": "Mr Cool",
    "ican": [
      {
        "subcategory": [
          {
            "id": "5bffdba824488b182ec86f8d", "name": "Cricket"
          },
          {
            "id": "5bffdba824488b182ec86f8c", "name": "Footbal"
          }
        ],
        "category": "5bffdba824488b182ec86f88",
        "name": "Sports"
      }
    ]
  }
]

// query
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "ican.subcategory.name": { $in: ["Cricket","Football"] }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": { "_id": 1, "name": 1, }
  }
])
```

I'm getting the combined result, I need the individual match record. I tried `$all` and `$elementMatch` but getting the same response. how can I get the results as below. I'm using `$aggregate` because I will be using `$geoNear` pipeline for getting the nearby users.

```
// current result
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "name": "Mr Cool"
  }
]

// expected result
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "name": "Mr Cool",
    "subcategory: "Cricket"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "name": "Mr Cool",
    "subcategory: "Footbal"
  }
]
```

Thank you

Comment: What if `ican` will also have  multiple elements?

Comment: Yes, it will have multiple elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EQDZ9D8iPyE)

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {"$unwind" : "$ican"},
    {"$unwind" : "$ican.subcategory"},
    {"$match" : {"ican.subcategory.name": { "$in": ["Cricket","Football"] }}},
    {"$group" : {"_id" : null,"data" : {"$push" : {"_id" : "$_id","name" : "$name","subcategory" : "$ican.subcategory.name"}}}},
    {"$unwind" : "$data"},
    {"$replaceRoot" : {"newRoot" : "$data"}}
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, will try this.

Comment: Cheers :) if you want group by id you can use "_id" : "$_id" instead of "_id" : null

Comment: just curious to know other possibilities, using `$project` or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation without the [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and for better performance

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "ican.subcategory.name": { "$in": ["Cricket","Football"] }}},
  { "$project": {
    "ican": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$ican",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": {
          "$concatArrays": [
            { "$filter": {
              "input": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$$this.subcategory",
                  "as": "s",
                  "in": { "name": "$name", "subcategory": "$$s.name" }
                }
              },
              "as": "fil",
              "cond": { "$in": ["$$fil.subcategory", ["Football"]] }
            }},
            "$$value"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$ican" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$ican" }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and your time, this query also works so well. dose using `$unwind` decrease the performance for the query.

Comment: Yes. `$unwind` is the expensive Stage in aggregation

Comment: Oh, Okay. seems like i have to spend more time on reading the docs :) Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I found an issue with this query, it's not filtering the data from the array, if I have only football in the array it's showing both the cricket and football https://mongoplayground.net/p/-fa2E-tIC2P

Comment: we have to fill the array with the passing array? is this efficient.

Comment: @sanprodev Yes it will always be efficient as compared to `$unwind`